# What are the advantages of using a Bayesian neural network

Tags: bayesian, neural-networks, bayesian-network

Recently I read some papers about the Bayesian neural network (BNN) [[Neal, 1992]](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~radford/ftp/bbp.pdf), [[Neal, 2012]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.1901), which gives a probability relation between the input and output in a neural network. Training such a neural network is through MCMC which is different from the traditional back-propagation algorithm.

My question are: What is the advantage of using such a neural network? More specifically, could you provide some examples which better fit BNN rather than NN?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bayesian neural nets are useful for solving problems in domains where data is scarce, as a way to prevent overfitting. They often beat all other methods in such situations. Example applications are molecular biology ([for example this paper](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2011/07/29/bioinformatics.btr444.full.pdf+html)) and medical diagnosis (areas where data often come from costly and difficult expiremental work). Actually, Bayesian nets are univerally useful and can obtain better results for a vast number of tasks but they are extremely difficult to scale to large problems.

Comment: Can you expand on why Bayesian nets are difficult to scale?

Answer (score 6):

One advantage of the BNN over the NN is that you can automatically calculate an error associated with your predictions when dealing with data of unknown targets. 
With a BNN, we are now doing Bayesian inference. Let's define our BNN prediction as $\bar{f}(x′|x,t)=∫f(x′,ω)p(ω|x,t)dω$, where $f$ is the NN function, $x'$ are your inputs, $ω$ are the NN parameters, and x,t are the training inputs and targets. This should be compatible with the syntax used by Neal in the links provided by @forecaster. Then we can calculate a standard deviation of the posterior predictive distribution, which I would naively use as an accuracy on the prediction : $\sigma(x′)=\sqrt{∫[f(x′,ω)−\bar{f}(x′|x,t)]^2p(ω|x,t)dω}$

Comment: This is an interesting addition to the conversation, but it is a bit short by our standards. Could you elaborate a bit and perhaps include a reference?

Comment: Sure. With a BNN, we are now doing Bayesian inference. Let's define our BNN prediction as $\bar{f}(x'|x,t) = \int{f(x',\omega)p(\omega|x,t) d\omega}$, where f is the NN function, x' are your inputs, $\omega$ are the NN parameters, and $x,t$ are the training inputs and targets. This should be compatible with the syntax used by Neal in the links provided by @forecaster. Then we can calculate a standard deviation of the posterior predictive distribution, which I would naively use as an accuracy on the prediction : $\sigma(x') = \sqrt(\int{[f(x',\omega)-\bar{f}(x'|x,t)]^2p(\omega|x,t) d\omega})$

Comment: Please edit this into your answer.